# Reading JSON array as one of the SQL table column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to read a json array into a table, one of the nodes (Languages) in the array is an array in itself, and I am getting `null` for this particular column (Languages).

Below is the sample json:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[
  {
     "Id":1,
     "Name":"Test1",
     "Languages":["L1", "L2"]
  },
  {
     "Id":2,
     "Name":"Test2",
     "Languages":["L3", "L4"]
  },
  {
     "Id":3,
     "Name":"Test2",
     "Languages":["L5", "L6"]
  }]'
```

Below is the query I am using:

```
SELECT Id
     , Name 
     , Languages
  FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (Id INT '$.Id'
     , Name VARCHAR(20) '$.Name'
     , Languages VARCHAR(200) '$.Languages')
```

Below is the current result:

[image]

However I need the result as below

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NVARCHAR(max) as json` for Language item inside `WITH` clause.

From Microsoft docs (all the details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)):

> If you don't specify AS JSON for a column, the function returns a
> scalar value (for example, int, string, true, false) from the
> specified JSON property on the specified path. **If the path represents
> an object or an array, and the property can't be found at the
> specified path, the function returns null** in lax mode or returns an
> error in strict mode. This behavior is similar to the behavior of the
> JSON_VALUE function.

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT Id
     , Name 
     , Languages
  FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (Id INT '$.Id'
     , Name VARCHAR(20) '$.Name'
     , Languages NVARCHAR(max) as json)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Andrea. this is what i was looking for, and thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

I hope maybe this query will be help you. Result is little bit different from you want.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"UserLang":[
  {
     "Id":1,
     "Name":"Test1",
     "Languages":["L1", "L2"]
  },
  {
     "Id":2,
     "Name":"Test2",
     "Languages":["L3", "L4"]
  },
  {
     "Id":3,
     "Name":"Test2",
     "Languages":["L5", "L6"]
  }]}'

SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(d.value,'$.Id') AS Id,
JSON_VALUE(d.value,'$.Name') AS Languages,
l.value AS Name
  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.UserLang') AS d CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (d.value,'$.Languages') AS l
```

Comment: Thanks Erdere, I am using the exact same query as a work around for now, however i was checking if there exists a way to putt the array directly into the column as a text.